Ground and power plane for this simple 2-layer PCB
I have a relatively simple PCB which I designed to manage some features of a analogue door bell system:

enable/disable the call,
detect the call,
open the door,
play some piezo status sounds.

As I am a beginner, I started with KiCad which is a bit complex, but I must say, it is understandable. It is not finished yet, but almost:


I do use a ground plane on layer B.Cu, as it makes routing easier. But now I wonder, if it would make sense - it shall be a 2-layer board - to also add a power plane. There is no high current and there are no high frequencies, so I think it is not really required.
But would it be bad practise? If it makes routing simpler, is there a reason not to do so?

The cheap prototype services will do small 4 later boards like that for a few dollars, so while you do not need more than 2 layers, if it saves you even a few minutes work it's probably worth it for a low volume board. It's a little weird to mix THT and SMD passives like that, but aside from wasting a bit of space it doesn't hurt anything if that's what you want to use.

Indeed a bit weird, but the reason is that I want to test both. It is my first PCB at all :)

Can you show the schematics? BC337 pinout may be incorrect.

@Justme Too bad I can't upload the full SVG, as it is a bit huge. But I added the part with the transistors now to the post.

@Tintenfisch Yes they are incorrect. Swap emitter to GND and collector to relay.

@Justme Thank you, let me check that!

@Justme Hmm, I am confused. I also tested it on the breadboard. I do collect GND on the collector (1) and emit it on the emitter (3) which then goes into the relay. Why is that wrong?

@Tintenfisch Because you connect NPN emitter to ground and the load to collector for proper operation. You might ask a new question about it, but it is likely asked and answered already. The problem is, BJTs are able to work upside down under some conditions but just poorly with somewhat less gain. So if you look at other examples how to use transistors, it's always the opposite of what you do, and how you do it is generally mentioned as a curiosity, if at all.

@Justme Now I did understand it, I created an own thread for it. Thanks a lot for finding this error in the schematics!

It is good practice to reserve half the layers for planes.  How those planes are divided (among nets in the design) depends on design goals (noise immunity, power level?) and net priority.
Ground is normally the single largest (most connected) net, and the most important to have a low impedance between points, so is a given in any design.
With two layers, that's it, you've chosen half the layers as planes.
Note that you will inevitably need to cross layers, thus creating negative space in your precious contiguous ground plane.  This is fine as long as the perimeter of the created slot is kept small, or it is shorted across with top-side ground and stitching vias.
Everything else must be routed.  Power traces can be routed with wider width (to increase ampacity and reduce high-frequency impedance), or even locally poured (as long as it's not obstructing other trace routing or component placement, or, a suitable compromise should be found), and most likely should have bypass capacitors placed regularly along the length, to keep impedance low.
A typical 2-layer design pours GND both sides, prefers component placement (SMTs preferred) and routing on the top side, and bottom-side routing is preferred crosswise to any top-side matter (buses of traces, rows of component pads, etc.), and routed and stitched such that, as much as possible, there is always ground above or below any given trace, pad or component, and clear areas (negative space through both top and bottom ground pours: traces crossing traces or rows of pads) are kept to a minimum.  The overall effect is, although either pour might be frequently interrupted by traces or component pads, both together, joined by judiciously, liberally placed stitching vias, act as one single plane on average.
Conversely, you would not pour power on one side, GND the other, because traces and components create negative space in it which you then have to stitch around -- but you can't stitch one pour without creating voids in the other, it's a losing proposition.  You can come up with a compromise, where enough linking traces and vias are present to keep each net impedance low enough, but now your design is difficult to maintain: suppose you have to move some components, or substitute, or add more new; you'll have to rip up a lot of this detailed work, you've got no help from the tool (it's all connected copper already, the ratsnest is no help here; and it's an unconventional stitching strategy, not simply vias strewn about), and you're that much more likely to make mistakes, omitting joins where they are needed.  Or, you stitch in the AC sense: bypassing VDD to GND with a capacitor, at each location you would otherwise introduce stitching; or similarly, use jumper components over gaps, effectively creating a local 3rd layer to jump over traces/buses where most important.  But now you're increasing BOM and assembly cost, and, is that really worth it compared to just getting the 4-layer board?
Mind, these reasons won't apply in all situations -- a very simple design might indeed successfully route in this way.  It's not clear if this would be your case, but it does look like there are enough ratsnest lines going in enough directions that additional routing, and crossings, will be necessary.  Supply nets are not indicated so I can't tell how much advantage that might give, versus the burden of cutting it up for whatever traces need to be routed.
Speaking of tools -- connectivity is connectivity.  Whether the traces or pours are thick/wide enough, only you can know.  (In some cases, this can be input as design rules -- trace width per net for example -- but many tools cannot check pours or other geometry for minimum width.)  If you depend on a pour for connectivity, but don't check how it's connected and where current is flowing, you might just create a minimum-width pinch point carrying full load current (whatever that is), and now you get all sorts of ills (voltages don't match across the plane, local heating, or outright failure due to overheating and fusing; or lack of surge handling ability, to similar ends).  Another reason to prefer traces: they're easier to get right.
Finally, regarding high speed: edge rate is what matters.  For general-purpose applications where signal bandwidth is low, MCUs and other logic outputs can be tamed by setting weak GPIO pin drive strength, or slow slew rate, and using a source termination resistor as close to the pin driver as possible.

Run a DRC in KiCad to identify any potential issues such as overlapping traces, unconnected pins, or minimum clearance violations.

Two reasons I can think of for not using internal layers are cost and signal accessibility. The service you're using and the amount you're willing to spend will be the deciding factor for cost. The other comes into play because this your first PCB, but also in general for first iterations. Say you route a signal from one THT component to another THT component. Then you get the PCB and test it, and you realize that signal should actually connect the first THT component to a totally different one. If you used an external layer, you can test your theory by physically cutting the trace and soldering a wire to the right connections. If you only used an internal layer for that trace, you can't, and then getting this PCB to work becomes much more complex. So, up to you. I think you're probably fine using an internal layer personally. You could also get around this by routing a shorter trace and then a via to the power plane, so you can still access that signal if needed.

Internal layers on a 4-layer bord are general the ones used for ground and supplies, so I don't see you will experience the scenario you describe, unless you deibrately put signals on them when it can become an issue. And as said elsewhere, a 4 layer board does not cost much more.

@Justme that is a good point sure, but you can still have GND or PWR connections that are wrong and need to be changed post-fab.

True, so they go through track on outer layers and vias to one of the inner layers. So cut a trace and connect to a nearby suitable VCC or GND from another via with a jumper wire. Experienced people can even dig into inner layers and do modifications, with tools like dentists and surgeons use for people.

You can cut internal layers, it's just not very easy. I've done it with a dremel.
